# Applying width to absolutely positioned element went wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created my own dropdown lists, because I could not style default select inputs as I needed, but my list has wrong width. My drop down has width in percentage: `100%`. The list I'm displaying is hidden and has `position: absolute;` so I could display it on top of another elements. I need this list to be always the same width as my dropdown field, but if I set it's `width: 100%`, it does not take the same width. Go to this fiddle to see the problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/vaxobasilidze/c5aqhqcu/2/

How can I make my drop down button and list to have the same size? Also, I have tried `position: relative;` property and made it relative to my drop down, the width was right in this case, but the list did not appear on top of others, instead, it moved everything down. So, if there is a way, to make my list relative, but appear on top of others, that would be another option to solve the issue.

```js
$('body').on('click touchend', '#typeSelect', function() {
  $('#typeDropDownList').toggle();
});

$('body').on('click touchend', '.typeSelect', function() {
  var Classes = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $('.typeDropDownList').hide();
  $('.' + Classes[0] + 'List').toggle();
});

$('body').on('click touchend', '.active', function() {
  var Classes = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");
  $('.' + Classes[0] + 'List').hide();
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  var container = $("#typeSelect");
  var container1 = $("#typeDropDownList");
  if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0 && !container1.is(e.target) && container1.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    container1.hide();
  }
});
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  var container = $(".typeSelect");
  var container1 = $(".typeDropDownList");
  if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0 && !container1.is(e.target) && container1.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    container1.hide();
  }
});

$('body').on('click touchend', '#typeDropDownList li', function() {
  var value = $(this).text();
  $('#typeSelect .type').text(value);
  $('#typeDropDownList').toggle();
  showTable();
});
$('body').on('click touchend', '.typeDropDownList li', function() {
  var value = $(this).text();
  $('.active .type').text(value);
  $('.typeDropDownList').hide();
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #2c2c2c;
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #2c2c2c), color-stop(37%, #3d3d3d), color-stop(66%, #353535), color-stop(66%, #353535), color-stop(100%, #131313));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2c2c2c', endColorstr='#131313', GradientType=1);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #b8c0c8;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#leftDiv {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
  position: relative;
}

#settingsDiv {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#mainDiv {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 75%;
  min-width: 700px;
  min-height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 3px;
}

#settingsDiv {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.adapterSettings {
  width: 100%;
}

.adapterSettings table {
  width: 100%;
}

.adapterInput select {
  width: 100%;
}

.adapterInput input {
  width: 100%;
}

.adapterInput * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#typeSelect {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  background-image: url(images/comment-bg.png);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: 300px;
  width: 353px;
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  color: #b8c0c8;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgb(76, 76, 76);
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1) 0%, rgba(89, 89, 89, 1) 18%, rgba(102, 102, 102, 1) 33%, rgba(71, 71, 71, 1) 74%, rgba(44, 44, 44, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1)), color-stop(18%, rgba(89, 89, 89, 1)), color-stop(33%, rgba(102, 102, 102, 1)), color-stop(74%, rgba(71, 71, 71, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(44, 44, 44, 1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1) 0%, rgba(89, 89, 89, 1) 18%, rgba(102, 102, 102, 1) 33%, rgba(71, 71, 71, 1) 74%, rgba(44, 44, 44, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1) 0%, rgba(89, 89, 89, 1) 18%, rgba(102, 102, 102, 1) 33%, rgba(71, 71, 71, 1) 74%, rgba(44, 44, 44, 1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1) 0%, rgba(89, 89, 89, 1) 18%, rgba(102, 102, 102, 1) 33%, rgba(71, 71, 71, 1) 74%, rgba(44, 44, 44, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1) 0%, rgba(89, 89, 89, 1) 18%, rgba(102, 102, 102, 1) 33%, rgba(71, 71, 71, 1) 74%, rgba(44, 44, 44, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4c4c4c', endColorstr='#2c2c2c', GradientType=0);
}

#typeSelect li {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}

#typeDropDownList {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  color: #b8c0c8;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

#typeDropDownList li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  /*background-image:url(images/cusel-bg-1.png);*/
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: 300px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgb(76, 76, 76);
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1) 0%, rgba(89, 89, 89, 1) 18%, rgba(102, 102, 102, 1) 33%, rgba(71, 71, 71, 1) 74%, rgba(44, 44, 44, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1)), color-stop(18%, rgba(89, 89, 89, 1)), color-stop(33%, rgba(102, 102, 102, 1)), color-stop(74%, rgba(71, 71, 71, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(44, 44, 44, 1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1) 0%, rgba(89, 89, 89, 1) 18%, rgba(102, 102, 102, 1) 33%, rgba(71, 71, 71, 1) 74%, rgba(44, 44, 44, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1) 0%, rgba(89, 89, 89, 1) 18%, rgba(102, 102, 102, 1) 33%, rgba(71, 71, 71, 1) 74%, rgba(44, 44, 44, 1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1) 0%, rgba(89, 89, 89, 1) 18%, rgba(102, 102, 102, 1) 33%, rgba(71, 71, 71, 1) 74%, rgba(44, 44, 44, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1) 0%, rgba(89, 89, 89, 1) 18%, rgba(102, 102, 102, 1) 33%, rgba(71, 71, 71, 1) 74%, rgba(44, 44, 44, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4c4c4c', endColorstr='#2c2c2c', GradientType=0);
}

#typeDropDownList li:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}

#typeDropDownList li:last-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}

#adapterSettings {
  background: url(images/comment-bg2.png);
}

.adapterInput {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

#adapterInputContainer {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 10px;
}

#adapterInputContainer tr {
  line-height: 20px;
}

#adapterInputContainer tr td:first-child {
  width: 50%;
}

.typeSelect {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  width: 353px;
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  color: #b8c0c8;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgb(76, 76, 76);
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1) 0%, rgba(89, 89, 89, 1) 18%, rgba(102, 102, 102, 1) 33%, rgba(71, 71, 71, 1) 74%, rgba(44, 44, 44, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1)), color-stop(18%, rgba(89, 89, 89, 1)), color-stop(33%, rgba(102, 102, 102, 1)), color-stop(74%, rgba(71, 71, 71, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(44, 44, 44, 1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1) 0%, rgba(89, 89, 89, 1) 18%, rgba(102, 102, 102, 1) 33%, rgba(71, 71, 71, 1) 74%, rgba(44, 44, 44, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1) 0%, rgba(89, 89, 89, 1) 18%, rgba(102, 102, 102, 1) 33%, rgba(71, 71, 71, 1) 74%, rgba(44, 44, 44, 1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1) 0%, rgba(89, 89, 89, 1) 18%, rgba(102, 102, 102, 1) 33%, rgba(71, 71, 71, 1) 74%, rgba(44, 44, 44, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1) 0%, rgba(89, 89, 89, 1) 18%, rgba(102, 102, 102, 1) 33%, rgba(71, 71, 71, 1) 74%, rgba(44, 44, 44, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4c4c4c', endColorstr='#2c2c2c', GradientType=0);
}

.typeSelect li {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}

.typeSelect input {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  color: #b8c0c8;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.typeDropDownList {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  color: #b8c0c8;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 48%;
}

.typeDropDownList li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  /*background-image:url(images/cusel-bg-1.png);*/
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: 300px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgb(76, 76, 76);
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIwJSIgeTI9IjEwMCUiPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzRjNGM0YyIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjE4JSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzU5NTk1OSIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjMzJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzY2NjY2NiIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9Ijc0JSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzQ3NDc0NyIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEwMCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiMyYzJjMmMiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPgogIDwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+CiAgPHJlY3QgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1) 0%, rgba(89, 89, 89, 1) 18%, rgba(102, 102, 102, 1) 33%, rgba(71, 71, 71, 1) 74%, rgba(44, 44, 44, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1)), color-stop(18%, rgba(89, 89, 89, 1)), color-stop(33%, rgba(102, 102, 102, 1)), color-stop(74%, rgba(71, 71, 71, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(44, 44, 44, 1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1) 0%, rgba(89, 89, 89, 1) 18%, rgba(102, 102, 102, 1) 33%, rgba(71, 71, 71, 1) 74%, rgba(44, 44, 44, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1) 0%, rgba(89, 89, 89, 1) 18%, rgba(102, 102, 102, 1) 33%, rgba(71, 71, 71, 1) 74%, rgba(44, 44, 44, 1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1) 0%, rgba(89, 89, 89, 1) 18%, rgba(102, 102, 102, 1) 33%, rgba(71, 71, 71, 1) 74%, rgba(44, 44, 44, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1) 0%, rgba(89, 89, 89, 1) 18%, rgba(102, 102, 102, 1) 33%, rgba(71, 71, 71, 1) 74%, rgba(44, 44, 44, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4c4c4c', endColorstr='#2c2c2c', GradientType=0);
}

.typeDropDownList li:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}

.typeDropDownList li:last-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}

.adapterSettings {
  background: url(images/comment-bg2.png);
  padding: 0;
}

.adapterInput {
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 80px;
}

.arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: -5px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  float: right;
  background: rgb(17, 17, 17);
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(17, 17, 17, 1) 0%, rgba(84, 84, 84, 1) 32%, rgba(61, 61, 61, 1) 64%, rgba(19, 19, 19, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(17, 17, 17, 1)), color-stop(32%, rgba(84, 84, 84, 1)), color-stop(64%, rgba(61, 61, 61, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(19, 19, 19, 1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(17, 17, 17, 1) 0%, rgba(84, 84, 84, 1) 32%, rgba(61, 61, 61, 1) 64%, rgba(19, 19, 19, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(17, 17, 17, 1) 0%, rgba(84, 84, 84, 1) 32%, rgba(61, 61, 61, 1) 64%, rgba(19, 19, 19, 1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(17, 17, 17, 1) 0%, rgba(84, 84, 84, 1) 32%, rgba(61, 61, 61, 1) 64%, rgba(19, 19, 19, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(17, 17, 17, 1) 0%, rgba(84, 84, 84, 1) 32%, rgba(61, 61, 61, 1) 64%, rgba(19, 19, 19, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#111111', endColorstr='#131313', GradientType=0);
}

.type {
  min-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="leftDiv">
    <div id="settingsDiv">
      <table style="width: 100%;" id="adapterSettings">
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2">Adapter</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="adapterInput" colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
            <ul id="typeSelect">
              <li><span class="type">--- TYPE ---</span><span class="arrow"><img src="https://www.materialui.co/materialIcons/navigation/arrow_drop_down_white_192x192.png" width="100%" height="100%" alt="arrow" title="arrow" /></span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="typeDropDownList">
              <li>--- TYPE ---</li>
              <li>DVB-S</li>
              <li>DVB-S2</li>
              <li>DVB-T</li>
              <li>DVB-T2</li>
              <li>DVB-C</li>
            </ul>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <table id="adapterInputContainer">
          <tr>
            <td>DYSEQ-port:</td>
            <td class="dyseq adapterInput">
              <ul class="dyseq typeSelect">
                <li><span class="type">0</span><span class="arrow"><img src="https://www.materialui.co/materialIcons/navigation/arrow_drop_down_white_192x192.png" width="100%" height="100%" alt="arrow" title="arrow" /></span></li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="dyseqList typeDropDownList">
                <li>0</li>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
                <li>4</li>
              </ul>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have applied padding to the drop-down menu field and not to the drop-down, either add to both or change the `padding` in `typeSelect` to

```
padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/buttflattery/c5aqhqcu/3/) for demo,hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This does not work. Could you please edit the fiddle? Maybe there is something else in my code.

Comment: just added a fiddle see if that is what you are looking for @VaxoBasilidze , look the edited answer for fiddle link

Comment: This looks kinda laggy, because there is no right margin. I have already written js function for that, but I wanted to do it with css. I'll post my function as an answer. Thank you for your help anyway :)

Comment: you can reduce the width to 99 % to keep distance from sides for menu and dropdown both `adapterInput` and `typeDropDownList` respectively

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I have written using JavaScript:

```
$('body').on('click touchend', '#typeSelect', function(){
    var width = $(this).width();
    $('#typeDropDownList').css({'width' : width+12}).toggle();
});
$(window).resize(function(){
    var width = $('#typeSelect').width();
    $('#typeDropDownList').css({'width' : width+12});
    var width1 = $('.typeSelect').width();
    $('.typeDropDownList').css({'width' : width1+12});
});
```

First function sets correct width on click, before displaying the list. And second one sets correct width if the window is resized. Adding this functions fixes the problem.